# How to check if a value is present in a POST form with Go's net/http?

Tags: go, post, http-post

According to the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.PostFormValue):

> PostFormValue returns the first value for the named component of the POST, PATCH, or PUT request body.
> URL query parameters are ignored.
> PostFormValue calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary
> and ignores any errors returned by these functions.
> **If key is not present, PostFormValue returns the empty string.**

So the function `Request.PostFormValue(key string) string` returns an empty string when `key` does not exist in the POST body, but also when it exists and its value is empty.

How can I only check if the key is in the POST body, regardless of its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parse the form](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseForm) and then check to see if the [key is set](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Values.Has) in the [post form](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.PostForm).

```
req.ParseForm()
hasKey := req.PostForm.Has("key")
```